# How can I check when certain software was installed?

Tags: ubuntu-13.10

I just noticed that I have a piece of software that I wasn't aware about that is installed in my computer. I'm pretty sure I didn't install it. Now, it could've been installed automatically when I installed something else that uses it (case in point, Redis is installed, and Celery can be configured to use Redis). But on top of this, Redis is being run on startup, I doubt is it default behavior.

How can I check when and who installed Redis? I'm on Ubuntu 13.10

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of packages installed locally do this in your terminal:

```
      dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall
```

To save that list to a text file called packages on your desktop do this in your terminal:

```
      dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall > ~/Desktop/packages
```

For finding about redis use

```
      dpkg -s redis
```

We can also use the following command to get exact status (whether it is installed or not):

```
       $ dpkg-query -W -f='${Status} ${Version}\n' redis
```

Output:

```
       install ok installed 1.3.34-2
```

Comment: Ok, on dpkg -s redis it says "package 'redis' is not installed and no information is available". But it is installed, I can run redis-cli and redis-server is ran on startup.

Comment: You need to run `dpkg -s redis-server` .

Comment: Ok, you're right. But that still doesn't tell me when it was install, and by whome (who gave the command? user or some piece of software? does it come with linux? do parts of linux need to user it? etc?)

Comment: I guess that linux doesn't store information about how the software is installed .